Print lines between patterns with awk
Going back to this discussion:
Print all lines between two patterns, exclusive, first instance only (in sed, AWK or Perl)
The proposed solution fails once the ending pattern is a substring of the start pattern.
Example input:
aaa
PATTERNSTART
bbb
ccc
ddd
PATT
eee

Produces output failure:
awk '/PATT/{exit} f; /PATTERNSTART/{f=1}' dat

Gives empty return instead of expected
bbb
ccc
ddd

Corner cases:

If start pattern is not found nothing shall be done
If ending pattern is not encountered print from start pattern to end of file
Only first occurrence of start / end pattern pair to be considered

Not sure I found all corner cases. Corner cases beyond above might be treated canonically
.
Thanks.

What should happen if there's a second PATTERNSTART before encountering a PATT?

What if there is an end pattern followed by a start-end pair?

I guess OP already wrote: Only first occurrence of start / end pattern pair to be considered

The right answer depends on what you mean by the highly ambiguous term "pattern", see how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern and then [edit] your question to tell us what "pattern" means in your context (regexp or string, full or partial line, full or partial word, something else, additional criteria, etc.)

You must use regex start and end anchors to avoid matching partial patterns:
awk 'f && /^PATT$/{exit} f; /^PATTERNSTART$/{f=1}' dat

bbb
ccc
ddd

or else use string comparison and avoid regex altogether:
awk 'f && $0 == "PATT"{exit} f; $0 == "PATTERNSTART"{f=1}' dat


Spot on! Great!

Make sure you use anchors:
$ awk '/^PATT$/{exit};/^PATTERNSTART$/{f=1;next}; {if (f){print}}' file
bbb
ccc
ddd


As already noted in this case if ending pattern holds, so does start. To prevent that either use ^ and $ anchors, or directly say NOT starting pattern AND ending pattern for first pattern-action pair following way, let dat content be
aaa
PATTERNSTART
bbb
ccc
ddd
PATT
eee

then
awk '!/PATTERNSTART/&&/PATT/{exit} f; /PATTERNSTART/{f=1}' dat

gives output
bbb
ccc
ddd

Observe that it will behave different than solutions with anchor as it will trear e.g. PATTY as ending pattern. You need to refine your requirement to determine what would happen in such case.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
